# java ftp - download from guest account on server without login name or password

Tags: java, download, ftp

I am trying to download a file from a server. The server has a guest account without a login or password.

The code was adapted from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32031-ftp-in-java-using-apache-commons-net. The reply code is 220, which means "Service ready for new user", but the size of the downloaded file is 0 Bytes. The size of the file on the server is 845 Bytes.

Thank you for your time.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FtpTest {
  public static FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

  public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
  String ftpStr = "ftp.ncbi.nih.gov";
  String path = "ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/MapView/Mus_musculus/non_sequence/README";

    try {
                  ftp.connect(ftpStr);
              } catch (SocketException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    System.out.println(reply); //Output: 220

    System.out.println("Connected");

    File file = new File("README");
    FileOutputStream dfile = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ftp.retrieveFile(path,dfile);
    ftp.disconnect();

    System.out.println("Finished");
  }

}
```

Comment: You mention that you get "Connected Success" but do you get to "Connected" or not?  Maybe the code is throwing an exception before that?

Comment: I do not get any Exception before connection. But I clarified my post so that it now contains the exact reply code (220, which means "Service ready for new user").

Comment: And nothing shows up in your stderr or stdout files?  No unhandled exceptions being thrown out to the log?

Comment: Does "Finished" print successfully?

Comment: Finished prints successfully. I am not using logging but running the code in the IDE, which prints all exceptions. I would like to point out that automatic FTP download has to be used with care for the path specified in the example - the files are different in different folders corresponding to different species and can change between versions, which makes manual control of the files necessary after FTP download.

Answer (score 1):

To access an FTP server with a guest account (without username or password), you should use the username `anonymous` with an empty password.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is two years late, but I had the same issue. The variable remote in: `public boolean retrieveFile(String remote, OutputStream local) throws IOException`
expects a file name, not the the full address to the file. So you should pass "README" instead of path. Before doing that, you should change the working directory of your ftp client to "genomes/MapView/Mus_musculus/non_sequence"